# Could not create '.egg-info': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, package, pypi, python-wheel

Im trying to build and distribute my first package and am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com) video to do so.

```
C:.
│   README.md
│   setup.py
│
└───QPy
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───backtesting
    │       base_backtest.py
    │       pairs_backtest.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───data_getter
    │       data.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───finstats
    │       basic.py
    │       VaR.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    ├───pairs
    │       pairs.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───portfolio
            ef.py
            __init__.py
```

this is my file structure

and when i try to run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` i get the following error

`error: could not create 'QPy.egg-info': The system cannot find the file specified`

I've tried updating pip, updating setuptools and wheel but I dont really know what else there is I can do.